# How do I prevent form submission in Angularjs if I am submitting the form using enter key?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have applied validation to my form (It has only two fields) but don't know how to prevent it from submitting,Current flow is: After pressing enter key the student's name and marks are added on localstorage and are displayed on the screen from there but I am unable to prevent empty data from submitting.

These are my js functions:

```
$scope.searchEnter = function() {
    if (event.which == 13 && $scope.student != "") {
        $scope.addStudent();
    }
};
$scope.addStudent = function() {
    if ($scope.marks > 65) {
        var pass = true;
    } else {
        pass = false;
    }
    $scope.students.push({ 'studentName': $scope.student, 'Marks': parseInt($scope.marks), 'pass': pass });
    $scope.student = '';
    $scope.marks = '';
    localStorage['studentsList'] = JSON.stringify($scope.students);

};
```

This is the html part:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate name="studentForm" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="student_name">Student's Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input ng-model="student" ng-keyup="searchEnter()" type="text" class="form-control" id="student_name" ng-required="true" name="stdname">
                        <div ng-show="studentForm.stdname.$touched && studentForm.stdname.$invalid">
                            <small style="color:red; display:block;">Enter a valid name </small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="student_marks">Marks obtained</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input ng-model="marks" ng-keyup="searchEnter()" type="number" class="form-control" id="student_marks" ng-required="true">Press ENTER to insert student's data in the table.</div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: remove `type="submit"`

Comment: He wants to prevent to send empty data..

Comment: post your HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your *fields* are correctly validating, to prevent the `submit` you could use [**`ngDisabled`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive, as below:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Submit</button>
```

**EDIT:** Since the OP provided the **full code** I was able to give the correct answer, that is:

Change the check to:

```
if (event.which == 13 && $scope.student && $scope.marks) {
```

*Snippet* working based on your `code`:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
  
  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.students = [];

    $scope.searchEnter = function() {
      if (event.which == 13 && $scope.student && $scope.marks) {
        $scope.addStudent();
      }
    };

    $scope.addStudent = function() {
      console.log('addStudent called');
      $scope.students.push({
        'studentName': $scope.student,
        'Marks': $scope.marks,
        'pass': $scope.marks > 65
      });
      $scope.student = '';
      $scope.marks = '';
      localStorage['studentsList'] = JSON.stringify($scope.students);
    };
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate name="studentForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="student_name">Student's Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input ng-model="student" ng-keyup="searchEnter()" type="text" class="form-control" id="student_name" ng-required="true" name="stdname">
            <div ng-show="studentForm.stdname.$touched && studentForm.stdname.$invalid">
              <small style="color:red; display:block;">Enter a valid name </small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="student_marks">Marks obtained</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input ng-model="marks" ng-keyup="searchEnter()" type="number" class="form-control" id="student_marks" ng-required="true">Press ENTER to insert student's data in the table.</div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Tips:**

1. The `ngModel` `$scope.marks` is already a number, you don't need to to do any `parse`, so you can have `'Marks': $scope.marks`.
2. The check of `pass` can simply reduced to: `'pass': $scope.marks > 65`

Comment: I am not using any button, the data goes to the local storage after pressing enter.

Comment: Since you don't have any button, what's the problem in simple check: `if (!$scope.student || !$scope.marks) { // Not valid }`

Comment: I have updated the html also, This is my first time I am writing angularjs code, So i am confused in a few things...yes I guess I should try this.

Comment: Do this: `if (event.which == 13 && $scope.student && $scope.marks) {`

Comment: Ohk, thanks a lot, It worked, I was unnecessarily making it complex.